# Python how to make mysql Parameterized Query with arbitrarty number of values passed

Tags: python, mysql

**I am using pyhon3**

I need to make a sql query to **mysql** database  from a python program
The query has an in clause,  and I need an arbitrary (or varying)  numbers of values to be passed to the "in" clause. Consider this query below that has fixed number (3) values for in clause

```
    select column1 from mytable where uniqueid in(1,5,9);
```

for such known number of "uniqueid" values for the in cluase as show above, I  use a python parametrized query below

```
    myquery=("select column1 from mytable where uniqueid in(%s,%s,%s)")
    idvals=(1,5,9)
    mycursor=mydbconn.cursor(dictionary=True, buffered=True)
    mycursor.execute(myquery,idvals)
```

However, my problem is that the values send to "in" clause need to be an arbirtrary number of values (obtained from another query) ... for example see queries below  -

```
select column1 from mytable where uniqueid in(1,5,9,7,11);
select column1 from mytable where uniqueid in(2,4,1,11,9,13,97,66);
```

Which means that I need to pass a list of varying lenght to the query and more over the placeholder "%s" for parameters also need to be variable

How do I compose such a query where I can pass a list of arbitrary values as parameters to a sql query

Based on response from Martin below  I wrote the full program as follows

```
# this solution worked ( thanks Martin -- see below) 
valuecursor=dbconn.cursor(buffered=True)
valuequery="select uniqueid from sometable"
valuecursor.execute(valuequery);
valuelist=[i[0] for i in valuecursor.fetchall()]
valuetuple=tuple(valuelist)

queryBase = "select column1 from mytable where uniqueid in(%s)"
myquery = queryBase % ",".join('%s' for i in range(0, len(valuetuple)))
mycursor=dbconn.cursor(buffered=True)
mycursor.execute(myquery,)
```

Resulting query string and tuple are as expected

query string = "select column1 from mytable where uniqueid in(%s,%s,%s)"
valuetuple = ('1','5','9')

and this works like a song

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish it with this:

```
 queryBase = "select column1 from mytable where uniqueid in(%s)"
 invals = (1,5,9)
 myQuery = queryBase % ",".join('%s' for i in range(0, len(invals)))
```

The resulting myQuery is:

```
'select column1 from mytable where uniqueid in(%s,%s,%s)'
```

Then finish the query formulation:

```
myQuery = myQuery % idvals
```

Then finish the query to the database:

```
mycursor = mydbconn.cursor(dictionary=True, buffered=True)
mycursor.execute(myQuery)
```

Comment: Martin, thanks for your response. I am afraid my question wasnt clear enough, please see edited question  -

Comment: I still believe my solution will work for you.  It is based on the length of idvals, and can be any length.

Comment: Hi Martin - Thanks a lot - it worked as you explined - I edited  my question to accomodate more details based on your response ...

Answer (score 0):

If you  send a string with all ids , you can use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
myquery=("SELECT column1 FROM mytable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(uniqueid,%s)")
invals=('1,5,9',)
mycursor=mydbconn.cursor(dictionary=True, buffered=True)
mycursor.execute(myquery,invals)
```

Comment: Hi nbk, thanks for your response. I am am not sure if I understand how your response will allow a arbirtray length list of invals to be passed to query ... I edited my question to state problem more clearly

Comment: you have a list with two elements the second one is empty and first one has all ips as a string separated by comma, you can have a lot of ids in there, the limit is unknbown as far as i know, so give it a try